# Resource-Task table in MS Project

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2016, workload

Does anybody know how to export workload of single resources (columns) per task (rows) from MS Project? The result should look as follows:

.............Resource 1.....Resource 2.....Resource 3 Task
Task1...........2h....................4h....................2h
Task2...........0h....................8h....................8h
Task3...........4h....................2h....................0h
Anyone who knows how produce such table from MS Project file? I would be very grateful.

Comment: That is google work and supposed not to ask this kind of questions

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question. There is an MS Project feature that exports data for getting a report exactly the way the OQ needs, and that feature’s use is not trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can create an Excel Visual Report.

In the “**Report**” tab, select “**Visual Reports**”. In the dialog, select any Excel report from the “**Assignment usage**” tab (the “**Baseline Work Report**” worked for me). In the “**Select level of usage data to include in the report**” combo, choose the time-phased detail you need; unless you need a daily detail (e.g. hours per resource *per day*), you can leave the default “**Weeks**” option selected.

This will create an Excel document with two tabs. First tab will have a bar graph (you can ignore it). Second tab will have a pivot table with resource work data in it. Here you need to add the “**Task**” field to rows, and the “**Resources**” field to columns. You could also need to remove the extra work fields (remaining work, baseline work, and so) from the values list, and left the “**Work**” field only. You'll also need to drill down to the desired sub-task level.

I’m adding an image of the result I got form a small project file (it’s in spanish, but you’ll get it).

[image: Hours per task per resource table in Excel, created with MS Project Visual Reports]

Hope this helps. Greetings.